Degree of determinant of a (non-monic) matrix polynomial
Let $n=2, 3, \dots$ and consider the matrix polynomial $L(\lambda)=\sum_{k=0}^{\ell}A_k\lambda^k$, where $A_k \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$.
In the so-called monic case (or that can be made monic by inversion of the leading-order matrix), when $A_{\ell}$ is non-singular, we know that $\det(L(\lambda))$ has degree $n\times \ell$, see Gohberg, Lancaster, and Rodman, Matrix Polynomials.
When $A_{\ell}$ is singular, for sure, we will have  $deg(\det(L(\lambda)))<n\times \ell$, since $\det(A_{\ell})=0$. However, in the textbook above and around the internet, I could not find any formula or (iterative, I guess) algorithm to find the exact value of $deg(\det(L(\lambda)))$ when $A_{\ell}$ is singular. Does anyone know any result on this matter?
Thanks!
